# how write unit test case for $stateProvider.init() using jasmine in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angular-ui-router, jasmine

I'm unable to mock the `$stateProvider.init()` function in my unit test file

Here i'm giving original library file `angular-ui-router.js` file, and when i'm run the spec file while executing `$stateProvider.init()` it goes to original file, it is not going to which i have mocked.

If I'm not giving the `angular-ui-router.js` as reference , then injection error will getting.

I want can any any body tell me how to mock the `$stateProvider.init()` in my spec file.

My expectation is `expect($stateProvider.init).toHaveBeenCalled()`;

Comment: The question is why you test something that's already covered?

Comment: This is not related to specflow, you should remove the tag

Comment: how can we know whether the line is covered or not. We have to write expect($stateProvider.init).toHaveBeenCalled();